# PHP: replace words from list in .txt-file with *

Tags: php, replace, text-files

I've searched around the web for days now, and I can't get an answer for my problem...
**So this is what I need to do:**
I have an .txt-file which contains one word per line. Let's say it's called `list.txt`.
And I have another .txt-file called `text.txt` with random stuff in it.
Now I want to have a PHP-file which checks  if it finds words from `list.txt` in the `text.txt`-file and replace them with ******.
**THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR ANY HELP!**

Comment: Have you created the PHP file yet? You should definitely start by creating the PHP file.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php  . this will convert your two files into array and then do the loop comparison and write to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this as a kind of pseudocode, although it's PHP. It should guide you for your desired solution:

```
$content = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$censored = explode("\n", file_get_contents('list.txt'));
$content = str_replace($censored, '*****', $content);
file_put_contents('text.txt', $content);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$str=file_get_contents('text.txt');
$str=str_replace("list.txt","****",$str); 
file_put_contents('text.txt', $str);
```

Comment: Please add relevent details to your answer.